# Flutter: Right overflow by 35 pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am creating a MCQ page insde my Flutter App. All the questions and options are pulled from my API. But the question part isnt completely rendering due to this issue. I have two requests, how do I make this error go away and how do I display my options as radio buttons. As of now they appear like the image attached.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuizProvider quizP = Provider.of<QuizProvider>(context);       
    return Container(child: Column(
      children:<Widget> [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
               Html(
                data: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].content,)
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions.length == null
            ? Container(
          child: Center(child: Text("Opps , Looks like we don't have any questions"),),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, itemCount) {
            return RadioListTile(
              value: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].id,
              groupValue: _selectedValue,
              onChanged: (answer){
                setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = answer;
                 // if(quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].correct== false){
                  _selectedValue = _selectedValue+1;
                     // _incorrectQuestion = 'hi';//quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].id.toString();

                 // }
                });
              },
              title: Text("${ quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].content}"),

            );
          },
        ),
      ],

    ),
    );
```

quiz.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

Quiz quizFromJson(String str) => Quiz.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String quizToJson(Quiz data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Quiz {
  Quiz({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.url,
    this.category,
    this.randomOrder,
    this.passMark,
    this.draft,
    this.durationtest,
    this.getQuestions,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  int category;
  bool randomOrder;
  int passMark;
  bool draft;
  String durationtest;
  List<GetQuestion> getQuestions;

  factory Quiz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Quiz(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    url: json["url"],
    category: json["category"],
    randomOrder: json["random_order"],
    passMark: json["pass_mark"],
    draft: json["draft"],
    durationtest: json["durationtest"],
    getQuestions: List<GetQuestion>.from(json["get_questions"].map((x) => GetQuestion.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "url": url,
    "category": category,
    "random_order": randomOrder,
    "pass_mark": passMark,
    "draft": draft,
    "durationtest": durationtest,
    "get_questions": List<dynamic>.from(getQuestions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class GetQuestion {
  GetQuestion({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.getanswers,
  });

  int id;
  String content;
  List<Getanswer> getanswers;

  factory GetQuestion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetQuestion(
    id: json["id"],
    content: json["content"],
    getanswers: List<Getanswer>.from(json["getanswers"].map((x) => Getanswer.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "content": content,
    "getanswers": List<dynamic>.from(getanswers.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Getanswer {
  Getanswer({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.correct,
    this.questionId,
  });

  int id;
  Content content;
  bool correct;
  int questionId;

  factory Getanswer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Getanswer(
    id: json["id"],
    content: contentValues.map[json["content"]],
    correct: json["correct"],
    questionId: json["question_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "content": contentValues.reverse[content],
    "correct": correct,
    "question_id": questionId,
  };
}

enum Content { A, B, C, D }

final contentValues = EnumValues({
  "A": Content.A,
  "B": Content.B,
  "C": Content.C,
  "D": Content.D
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
               child: Html(
                data: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].content,)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```